# Valid name cannot accept only hyphen

Tags: regex

I am weak in regex but I am learning. Currently I have a requirement to validate name and I am not able to write a valid regex for it. A valid name would contain alphabet only or alphabet with hyphens or spaces.

Example of valid name would be

```
jones
jones-smiht
a loreal jones
```

but if the name contains digits it's an invalid name. The following regex

`^[-\\sa-zA-Z]+$` works fine but only `-` is also considered as a valid name.

How do I modify it so that a valid name must contain letters regardless or whether it contains hyphens and spaces?

Comment: Would you consider `-a` a valid name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z][-\\sa-zA-Z]*$
```

This will make sure your name always starts with a letter instead of starting with hyphen or space.

**Note:** In Java you can also make use of `(?i)` for ignore case and shorten your regex as follows:

```
(?i)^[a-z][-\\sa-z]*$
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad to know it worked. If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Answer (score 1):

The literal answer for you would be `^[a-zA-Z][-\sa-zA-Z]*$`.

There are better answers: for instance,

```
([a-zA-Z]+)([-\s][a-zA-Z]+)*
```

will allow any number of words separated by single space or dash, allowing for `simon peyton-jones`, but disallowing silliness like `--jumbo-spaz--`.

And copied from the response I tried to publish on the deleted answer:

> Regexp is single-backslash. However, since regexps are constructed from strings in Java, you need to escape the backslash; but it is the feature of strings, not of regexps. So, regexp is `\s`, but you need to write `Pattern.compile("\\s")` in Java. Not all languages have this twist, so keeping rules of strings separate from what Regexp is is useful.